# Error passing json array onclick- html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am generating a clickable list dynamically using jquery. here is the code that generates the list.

```
for(dayint=0;dayint < day_arr.length;dayint++){
                var temp_pass = JSON.stringify(day_arr[dayint]);
                //alert(temp_pass);
                $("#itin_list").append('<a  href="#" style= "border: 2px solid red;list-style-position: inside;min-height:500px; margin: 5px"  value="'+ temp_pass +'" class="list-group-item" onclick="sethiddendiv(this.value);"><b>Day  '+ dayint + ' of Trip from '+ start_n +' to '+ end_n +' </b> <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dirModal" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px; right:5px;float:right" class="btn btn-primary">Show Directions</button></a><br>');

            }
```

The problem I have is when passing the json array to my sethidddendiv function. The code sample for the function is as below:

```
window.sethiddendiv = function(str) {

        //var nisal = $.parseJSON(str);
        alert(str);
    }
```

When the list item is clicked, instead of giving the json array, it alerts "undefined" all the time.

Here is the html that is generated in the page when I inspect element:

```
<a href="#" style="border: 2px solid red;list-style-position: inside;min-height:500px; margin: 5px" value="[" 7.1896145,="" 79.7884585","7.9577778,="" 80.667518","8.3353156,="" 80.3329846"]"="" class="list-group-item" onclick="sethiddendiv(this.value);"><b>Day  0 of Trip from Colombo to  Kandy </b> <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dirModal" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px; right:5px;float:right" class="btn btn-primary">Show Directions</button></a>
```

What could be the issue here? 
I already tried using single quotes for the onclick, but it didnt work. Any help would be very welcome. I'm stuck.

Comment: For one, you have unescaped quotes in the value. And you probably don't want the equal signs in the value either.

Comment: I fixed this by just passing only an integer id in the value and doing a seperate ajax query to get details. it is really hard to get rid of the syntax issues in passing json through val.